# How to resolve tainted scalar coverity issue introduce by "byte swapping operation" in c

Tags: c, coverity

I am working in C - Coverity warning fixes.
New to TAINTED_SCALAR warnings.
I have this below code in which I get tainted scalar warning,

```
VOID func1 (UINT1 *p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket,
            UINT1 *p_u1Secret,
            UINT1 a_u1Concatenated[],
            INT4 *i4_Length)
{
    INT4                i4_seclen = 0;
    UINT2               u2_pktlen = 0;
    UINT1    a_u1RequestAuth[LEN_REQ_AUTH_AUTH] = {};
    INT4                        index = 0;

    if (p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
#if 0 // this part of code, when included, comes under dead code saying the if condition inside this for loop will never be stru and hence will never get hit. Hence commented out this code using "#if 0". When this code was added, the abouve NULL check is removed.
    for (index = 0; index < (PKT_LEN+2); index++)
    {
        if(!(p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket + index))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
#endif

    MEMSET (a_u1Concatenated, 0, LEN_RX_PKT + LEN_SECRET);

    MEMCPY (&u2_pktlen, p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket + PKT_LEN, 2);

    /* Validate the packet length to avoid  buffer overflow, denial of service,
     * memory corruption, or other security vulnerability. */
    if ((u2_pktlen < 20) || (u2_pktlen > 4096))
    {
        return;
    }

    u2_pktlen = OSIX_NTOHS (u2_pktlen); // this part of code says , "Performing a byte swapping operation on {0} implies that it came from an external source, and is therefore tainted.". Also says, "Assigning: {0} = {1}. Both are now tainted.}{{code{u2_pktlen}}}{{code{(UINT2)(((u2_pktlen &amp; 0xff00) &gt;&gt; 8) | ((u2_pktlen &amp; 0xff) &lt;&lt; 8))}}}

    MEMCPY (a_u1Concatenated, p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket, u2_pktlen); // This part of code says, "Passing tainted variable {0} to a tainted sink.}{{code{(size_t)u2_pktlen}}}" ==> eventSetCaption is "Tainted data flows to untainted sink".
    MEMCPY (a_u1RequestAuth, p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket + PKT_REQA,
            LEN_REQ_AUTH_AUTH);
    MEMCPY (a_u1Concatenated + PKT_REQA,
            a_u1RequestAuth, LEN_REQ_AUTH_AUTH);
    i4_seclen = STRLEN ((char *) p_u1Secret);
    MEMCPY (a_u1Concatenated + u2_pktlen, p_u1Secret, i4_seclen);
    *i4_Length = u2_pktlen + i4_seclen;
}
```

I have included the for loop to check if the received radiusPkt is not NULL until the required length to copy the "pktLen" field value. This was not working, instead throwing one more warning ie., dead code. Explained about this in the code.

Expected TAINTED_SCALAR warnings to be 0. But receiving TAINTED_SCALAR warning as 1 due to this issue.

Can anyone please help me to get rid of this TAINTED_SCALAR warning?

Comment: You already check if the pointer is NULL. Then you check if the pointer + something is NULL. What makes you think it would ever be executed? As far as I know, the result of pointer arithmetic can never be a null pointer.

Comment: @Lundin, when that check is added, the index was starting from 1. Will edit my post for this.

Answer (score 0):

The below code changes fix the issue and gives expected result.

```
VOID func1 (UINT1 *p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket,
            UINT1 *p_u1Secret,
            UINT1 a_u1Concatenated[],
            INT4 *i4_Length)
{
    INT4                i4_seclen = 0;
    UINT2               u2_pktlen = 0;
    UINT1    a_u1RequestAuth[LEN_REQ_AUTH_AUTH] = {};
    INT4                        index = 0;

    if (p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    MEMSET (a_u1Concatenated, 0, LEN_RX_PKT + LEN_SECRET);

    MEMCPY (&u2_pktlen, p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket + PKT_LEN, 2);

    u2_pktlen = OSIX_NTOHS (u2_pktlen);

    /* Validate the packet length to avoid buffer overflow, denial of service,
     * memory corruption, or other security vulnerability. */
    if ((u2_pktlen < 20) || (u2_pktlen > 4096))
    {
        return;
    }

    MEMCPY (a_u1Concatenated, p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket, u2_pktlen);
    MEMCPY (a_u1RequestAuth, p_u1RadiusReceivedPacket + PKT_REQA,
            LEN_REQ_AUTH_AUTH);
    MEMCPY (a_u1Concatenated + PKT_REQA,
            a_u1RequestAuth, LEN_REQ_AUTH_AUTH);
    i4_seclen = STRLEN ((char *) p_u1Secret);
    MEMCPY (a_u1Concatenated + u2_pktlen, p_u1Secret, i4_seclen);
    *i4_Length = u2_pktlen + i4_seclen;
}
```